PHP JWT not verified other than PHP
I am using PHP firebase JWT for implementation of JWT in my PHP app. Here is my code
    $payload = [
        'iss' => 'http://test.com',  
        'aud' => 'http://test.com',  
        'iat' => time(),  // Issued at
        'exp' => time() + 3600,  // Expiration (1 hour)
        'data' => [
            'user_id' => $user['id'],
            'email' => $user['email'],
            'role' => $user['role'],
            'is_admin' => $user['isadmin']
        ]
    ];
    $jwt = JWT::encode($payload, $key, 'HS256', $key_file);

After encoding it generates the token eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Ii92YXIvd3d3L215a2V5LmtleSJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOi8vdGVzdC5jb20iLCJhdWQiOiJodHRwOi8vdGVzdC5jb20iLCJpYXQiOjE3MjM5NzQ5OTMsImV4cCI6MTcyMzk3ODU5MywiZGF0YSI6eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoxLCJlbWFpbCI6ImFiYyIsInJvbGUiOiJ1c2VyIiwiaXNfYWRtaW4iOjB9fQ.uC13pivSZGnPr6i8zmPCfEFMsykWR5miIK8t0-DCnug
which is fine
The content of key file are hellohellohellohellohellohellohe
I used the website https://jwt.io/ to test my token and several other websites https://dinochiesa.github.io/jwt/
Now I want a normal user to generate a token through any website by changing the key kid parameter and using any of the website on the internet, so it can be used on the site (demonstrating a vulnerability).
I am facing two issues; if I try to verify the token with the above key on any of the websites with the key file, it says it cannot match or verify; what is the issue? Does PHP Firebase based JWT works differently?
I also checked this one
JWT signature not verifying in PHP

I just pasted your example token and secret into the debugger on https://jwt.io and it says "Signature Verified", so I'm not clear what you're asking. I'm also a bit confused what you mean by "changing the key kid parameter" - kid is just an informational field hinting which of multiple shared keys a user of the token should use to verify or decrypt the token, it doesn't influence the signature itself.

Here's a screenshot of the signature being verified: https://i.sstatic.net/Je1bka2C.png

@IMSoP please have a look https://ibb.co/WDs7Nk7
If you look at your JTW once it you paste the key, you will noticed that it has been changed.

Oh, I see what you mean. My guess is that $key does not contain what you think it does, e.g. you're reading it from a file which has extra characters such as line endings. Try using a string that's hard-coded in the PHP, so you can be confident exactly what it contains.

@IMSoP I was going through the source code, and it contains return \hash_hmac($algorithm, $msg, $key, true);
I have checked that before hashing, the key contains the correct value.

That line of code gives me enough information to prove that the value is not what you thought it was. It's not being changed anywhere, it's just that every time you've looked at it, you've overlooked a newline that's included at the end of it.

Because you're reading the key from a file, rather than testing with a hard-coded value, it's hard to see if there are extra characters included, such as line breaks.
If you generate the hash manually with what you thought was your key, you will see a different signature:
$msg = 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Ii92YXIvd3d3L215a2V5LmtleSJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOi8vdGVzdC5jb20iLCJhdWQiOiJodHRwOi8vdGVzdC5jb20iLCJpYXQiOjE3MjM5NzQ5OTMsImV4cCI6MTcyMzk3ODU5MywiZGF0YSI6eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoxLCJlbWFpbCI6ImFiYyIsInJvbGUiOiJ1c2VyIiwiaXNfYWRtaW4iOjB9fQ';
$key = 'hellohellohellohellohellohellohe';
$algorithm = 'SHA256';

$signature = hash_hmac($algorithm, $msg, $key, true);
echo base64_encode($signature);

#=> zBeba1d7bk/OhMeo5P/Aw1aO2v4JxW+8QXGJsCx1AWI=

But if you add a single newline on the end, you will see the signature in your sample JWT (apart from the slightly different variant of BASE64 encoding, with "-" vs "+"):
$msg = 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Ii92YXIvd3d3L215a2V5LmtleSJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOi8vdGVzdC5jb20iLCJhdWQiOiJodHRwOi8vdGVzdC5jb20iLCJpYXQiOjE3MjM5NzQ5OTMsImV4cCI6MTcyMzk3ODU5MywiZGF0YSI6eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoxLCJlbWFpbCI6ImFiYyIsInJvbGUiOiJ1c2VyIiwiaXNfYWRtaW4iOjB9fQ';
$key = "hellohellohellohellohellohellohe\n";
$algorithm = 'SHA256';

$signature = hash_hmac($algorithm, $msg, $key, true);
echo base64_encode($signature);

#=> uC13pivSZGnPr6i8zmPCfEFMsykWR5miIK8t0+DCnug=

You could do the same experiment directly with the JWT::encode function, but I don't have an environment to hand where I can install the library.
